# gmaps4rails v2 methods / functions / variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coffeescript, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

I was hoping for some clarification on when and where you can call certain methods.

- clusterer (Do you access this through the handler?  Do you clear the clusterer as a whole, or do you clear individual markers from the clusterer?)
- addListener (I see this sitting in base_builder.coffee, but have no idea how to interact with it)
- `@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@events) do |event, marker|` (Do all of the builders work here?)
- primitives (when, maybe why, would I need to use these?  I see it in the common.coffee, which is why I ask.  I don't want to be missing anything.)

I'm sure I'll have more, as I keep using it... but these should get me moving nicely.

**update**

new question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- clusterer (Do you access this through the handler? Do you clear the clusterer as a whole, or do you clear individual markers from the clusterer?)

In 2.0.4 you can do `handler.removeMarkers(array)` and `handler.removeMarker(marker)`

- addListener (I see this sitting in base_builder.coffee, but have no idea how to interact with it)

only useful if you create your own builder, you can access the same method thanks to the primitives, or write it with plain google maps commands: do you really need to abstract on your level?

- `@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@events) do |event, marker|` (Do all of the builders work here?)

It's just a convenient way to create json. If you need custom json, build it with your own json builder.

- primitives (when, maybe why, would I need to use these? I see it in the common.coffee, which is why I ask. I don't want to be missing anything.)

This is an abstraction in the gem: as an injected dependency it lets me test easily. You can use it, but its not required.

Comment: good point on the `addListener`.  using `google.maps.event.addListener` is fine by me.  Thanks for the clarification on some of the other things, and a **big** thanks for taking care of the clustering!

Comment: How about setZoom?  I feel as though I'd want to do handler.setZoom(18)... or handler.map.setZoom(18).  I couldn't find it in the code, if it's in there.

Comment: also... is there a `.getBounds` somewhere?

Comment: `handler.map.zoomTo(zoom_level)` and `handler.bounds`

Comment: `console.log Gmaps.store.handler.bounds.serviceObject.getNorthEast().toString()` gives me `-1, -180`, and I'm definitely zoomed in... I tried just .bounds, and it gives the same.  For zoomTo(), I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Map> has no method 'zoomTo'`.  Calling it with `Gmaps.store.handler.map.zoomTo(10)`

Comment: Oops, zoomTo is my own addition. Do `handler.getMap().setZoom()`. `handler.bounds` returns the proper object

Comment: `Gmaps.store.handler.getMap().zoomTo(10)` - `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<pi> has no method 'zoomTo'`.  For the Bounds... Shouldn't I be able to call `.getNorthEast()` on it to get a latLng object?  I updated my question above to show what the console is showing

Comment: Please ask a brand new question, i'll check it later. But are you sure of your store?